# Nightly show as Firefox in Dash

Tags: unity, .desktop

I have created the following .desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications`, when I search "Nightly" Nightly appears in search results with the correct icon(earth at night), but when I opened it it shows as Firefox in Dash. How can I make it show as Nightly? I used Fedora 19 with Fedora Desktop.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
NoDisplay=false
Exec=/home/yang/Apps/firefox/firefox %u
Name=Nightly
Comment=Custom definition for Nightly
Icon=/home/yang/Apps/firefox/browser/icons/mozicon128.png
```

Answer (score 0):

if firefox is already running, it do not open a new instance but connect to the old one (try to close firefox and open the link to see that it opens nightly)

what you need to do is to open it with --no-remote option

```
Exec=/home/yang/Apps/firefox/firefox --no-remote %u
```

EDIT:on some systems it -no-remote (one minus character)

Comment: No, it's not because of this

Answer (score 0):

two versions of firefox might have problem working on the same profile

try to open it with -P (in addition to --no-remote), for the first time it will open the profile manager, create another profile and from now on open it with

```
Exec=/home/yang/Apps/firefox/firefox --no-remote -P aurora %u
```

Comment: Not working either.